# Non-compactness of $D=\{f \in \mathcal{C}(\left[0,1\right])\mid \|f\|_{\infty}\leq 1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

In showing non-compactness of $D = \{ f \in \mathcal{C}([0,1]) \mid \|f\|_{\infty} \leq 1 \}$, I did the following:

$$f_n (x) = 
\begin{cases} 
    1-nx,\quad\quad 0\leq x \leq \frac{1}{n} \\\ 
    0; \quad\quad\quad\quad \frac{1}{n}\leq x \leq 1
\end{cases}$$
Now, there's no subsequence that converges, so $D$ cannot be compact. Is this argument valid?

EDIT: As $f_n$ converges pointwise to $0$ in $\left]0,1\right]$, but $f_n(0)=1$, one can conclude that there is no such convergent subsequence.

Comment: *(Edited)* Yes, your choice of counter-example looks good. As pointed out by Crostul, however, it will be much better if you show your understanding as to why this truly serves as a counter-example.

Comment: This argument is valid, but incomplete. You have to show it has no convergent subsequence.